# Weka : How to save regression predictions into file

Tags: regression, weka

I am trying to run linear regression in Weka. I have got the output labels for test files in console window, but how do I get the same into a CSV/text file?

Comment: Have you tried linux pipeline? :)

Comment: Oh! Never occurred to use Weka though commandline. Thanks!